# base64 as textbox background?

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, base64

I have a textbox that has an image linked as it's background.

I'd like to use the base64 version of this image.

I used a very simple windows -form- to ensure the code for enacting the base64 is working correctly, it did.

The part I'm having issue with is linking it in xaml in a wpf style gui.

```
<TextBox Name="OutTBox" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="6" Margin="20,5,20,20" Foreground="#FF8CFF8C" IsReadOnly="True" >
   <TextBox.Background>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\background.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
   </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

So here is the base64 language I used for the windows form:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

# Setup the XAML
[xml]$script:xaml = '<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    Title="base64 image demo" Height="350" Width="650" Background="Black">
<Grid>
    <Image Name="thisistheimage"  Stretch="UniformToFill" />
</Grid>
</Window>'

# Create the form and set variables
$script:form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml))
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object { Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $form.FindName($_.Name) -Scope Script }

# here's the base64 string

$base64 = "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"

# Create a streaming image by streaming the base64 string to a bitmap streamsource
$bitmap = New-Object System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage
$bitmap.BeginInit()
$bitmap.StreamSource = [System.IO.MemoryStream][System.Convert]::FromBase64String($base64)
$bitmap.EndInit()

# Freeze() prevents memory leaks.
$bitmap.Freeze()

# Set source here. Take note in the XAML as to where the variable name was taken.
$thisistheimage.source = $bitmap

# Show form
$null = $form.ShowDialog()
```

I'd give you my actual image but it's over 5k lines long. It only takes a fraction of a second to load.
To be clear the base64 will load in the Xaml. I removed the textbox from those grid coords and replaced it with the base64 and it loads fine. just can't seem to work the two together.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you don't know how to put the bitmap into an ImageBrush and assign that to the Background property of a TextBox?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Perhaps I'm using the wrong search terminology when looking for a solution. I've been searching for strictly a base64 image solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used powershell, but it should be as simple as this:

```
$brush = New-Object System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush
$brush.ImageSource = $bitmap

$thetextbox.Background = $brush
```

Comment: That definitely worked.
Thank you very much, indeed.
I don't mean to sound ungrateful but is there a more integrated method?

Comment: ImageBrush has a constructor with an ImageSource parameter where you could pass `$bitmap`. Not sure about the powershell syntax, but maybe you can write `$thetextbox.Background = New-Object System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush($bitmap)`.

Comment: And believe me, I tried this. Well before even googling the answer I tried presenting the variable as the image source but it never showed. 

Perhaps where I placed the base64 conversion was in the wrong place.


I tried loading the presentation, then bitmap conversion, the xaml and finally the reader. It would not load the gui at all.

I'm using interpretive here-string @" "@ not the @' '@ restrictive version.


I'm currently looking at the drawingbrush as a potential answer but not seeing it.

Comment: Not sure what a DrawingBrush has got to do with this. Anyway, as a general hint, you should usually set `$bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` before calling `EndInit()` when you load a BitmapImage from a Stream. You can then close the Stream immediately after EndInit.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'll use that advice. In regards to the DrawingBrush, I'm cycling through these microsoft docs on imagebrush and drawings. it seems these pages are linked in lots of the results I get but in the end I'm not finding the complete answer. [Painting with Images and Drawings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/painting-with-images-drawings-and-visuals)

Comment: Your base64 string encodes a bitmap. You can only display it by means of an ImageBrush. A DrawingBrush is meant to contain vector graphics, which you don't have.

Comment: @Clemens If you can do it in .net, you can do it in PowerShell, basically.